# PHP Не отображаются кириллические символы после извлечения одного символа из строковой переменной

Tags: php, кириллица, символы

Уважаемые гуру, помогите с ошибкой в простейшем коде. Извлекаю первый символ из строковой переменной, при отображении в echo латинские символы все ок, а кириллица дает знак вопроса. Премного благодарен за любую помощь.

```
<?php
$latname = "Bill";
echo ($latname);
echo "<br>\n";
echo ($latname[0]);
echo "<br>\n";

$cyrname = "Владимир";
echo ($cyrname);
echo "<br>\n";
echo ($cyrname[0]);
?>
```

Comment: потому что это мультибайтная строка и нужно с ней работать как с мультибайтной....напрример отрезать mb_  функцией первый символ

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?
$latname = "Bill";
echo ($latname);
echo "<br>\n";
$str = mb_str_split($latname);
echo ($str[0]);
echo "<br>\n";

$cyrname = "Владимир";
echo ($cyrname);
echo "<br>\n";
$str = mb_str_split($cyrname);
echo ($str[0]);
?>
```

Comment: `mb_substr($x,0,1)` вполне достаточно без разделения всей строки

Comment: Этот код выдает ошибку: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_str_split() in /...../www/send.php on line 48. Я коряво все же запустил через if для проверки кириллицы ASCII (меньше и больше 122) и substr для вырезки символа. Работает, символ правильный, но при запросе ord выдает для любой кириллической буквы одинаковый код 208.

Comment: mb_str_split() присутствует в PHP >= 7.4. Тут: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split в комментариях приведён полифил для этой функции.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь и советы. Проблема решилась крайне просто - в настройках сервера стояла старая версия РНР, сменил и все заработало.